# Determining if a substring contains a random number

Tags: java

I am trying to determine if a string contains a specific attribute.

I have a long string and want to determine if the attribute, v_lstg_#, is contained within that string but the problem that I am having is that the last character, in v_lstg_#, is an arbitrary integer, from 0-9, (hence the '#'), so my question is what regex (or any other method) can I use to determine if that attribute is contained within the string?

So something similar to:

```
String randomString;
randomString.contains("v_lstg_" + "some integer valued, ranged from 0 - 9, regex here")
```

Comment: Without seeing the format of `randomString` we can't know. That is, can we think of this String as a series of fields? How are the fields presented? What is the format of the value after this field (i.e., all numeric, alphanumeric, spaces, nulls, is it a fixed width... ?) Once you have this information you might also get some idea of potential solutions. Maybe a regex is not the right way to do this?

Comment: Obligatory: http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: @jdv Well, the format of the string really is irrelevant. Suppose I have two words in a sentence and I want to verify that "v_lstg_#" is contained within that sentence. The only issue is that `#` is a random integer.

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes??

Comment: It is _extremely_ relevant. Define "random number". 7 is a random number, but one assumes it is some non-fixed-width decimal value. Which I only understood by digging around in your question and after these comments. Edit this question to show an example, and list any restrictions and specific criteria. The more you make anyone work for it, the less attention you'll get.

Comment: Better yet, drop the word "random" entirely. It is irrelevant, for these purposes, what the source of this number is. Instead, describe what the number looks like or could look like. Is 157 a possibility? Is 3.14159? How about 2+5i?

Comment: Maybe show an example String? So far I'm guessing you might have something like "Badger Badger Badger v_lstg_42 Mushroom Mushroom", perhaps without spaces, and maybe not containing the string "v_lstg_". What are the constraints on the value, if present.

Comment: You might mean "arbitrary" rather than "random".

Comment: @AndyTurner Arbitrary is the better word. Thank you. Also, I updated my question.

Comment: Also, once you've decided to use a regex, it can be fun to play around with http://www.regexr.com/ to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `contains()`. It's a regular expression, at heart, so use `matches()`:

```
boolean matches = randomString.matches(".*v_lstg_\\d.*");
```

**ETA**: Request was made to separate the `v_lstg_` part from the rest of it:

```
String prefix = "v_lstg_";
boolean found = randomString.matches(".*"+prefix+"\\d.*");
```

Comment: Hmm is there a way to seperate the word "v_lstg_" from the regex you provided so something like v_lstg_ + regex? Also, to clarify, the arbitrary integer is from 0 - 9.

Comment: `\\d` matches any single digit, 0 included. And obviously, you could pull out the "v_lstg_" part ... see edit. I'd further note this would match multiple-digit numbers. That didn't seem to be part of the original request, but if that's a problem the regex would need to be modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

here's another example...using the regex Pattern and Matcher classes. If you only want the number then you could research regex grouping to pull that out. Regexes can get insane so be careful.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Debug {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "v_lstg_124536someotherstuff";
    String regex = "(v_lstg_\\d+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(m.find());
    System.out.println(s.subSequence(m.start(), m.end()));

  }
}
```

here's an example with teh grouping

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "v_lstg_124536someotherstuff";
    String regex = "(v_lstg_)(\\d+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(m.find());
    System.out.println(s.subSequence(m.start(), m.end()));
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
  }
```

which prints

```
true
v_lstg_124536
v_lstg_
124536
```